# KeyError at /users/login 'isLoggedIn'

Tags: django, python-2.7

So the error is in line 29 of my views.py file. However I can't seem to find where the issue lies.  my views and my models.py file look fine. It happens when you click the login button on the login page.  I did go though and reident the whole def login . And the functions of else after the line 29 does work in that if i put in bad info it throws the message like ti should. so it is just the the if statement

MultiValueDictKeyError at /users/login
"u'email'"    error is line 29in the view py

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\django2\loginReg\loginReg\apps\logReg\views.py" in login
  29.   if viewsResponse['isLoggedIn']:

Exception Type: KeyError at /users/login
Exception Value: 'isLoggedIn'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login and Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="register">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form class="" action="{% url 'users:register' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" value=""></p>
            <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" value=""></p>
            <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" value=""></p>
            <p>Password: <input type="Password" name="password" value=""></p>
            <p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirm_password" value=""></p>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <form class="" action="{% url 'users:login' %}" method="post">
        <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" value=""></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="Password" name="password" value=""></p>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
import re, bcrypt
EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$')

class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def add_user(self, postData):
        errors = []
        if not len(postData['first_name']):
            errors.append('First name is required')
        if len(postData['last_name']) < 2:
            errors.append('Last name must be at least 2 characters long!')
        if not len(postData['email']):
            errors.append('Email is required!')
        if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(postData['email']):
            errors.append('Please enter a valid email!')
        check_email = self.filter(email = postData['email'])
        if check_email:
            errors.append('Sorry email already exist!')
        if len(postData['password']) < 8:
            errors.append('Password must be at least 8 characters!')
        if not postData['password'] == postData['confirm_password']:
            errors.append('Passwors must match!')

        modelsResponse = {}

        if errors:
            # failed validations
            modelsResponse ['isRegistered'] = False
            modelsResponse['errors'] = errors
        else:
            # passed validations, create a new user
            hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(postData['password'].encode(), bcrypt.gensalt())
            user = self.create(first_name = postData['first_name'] , last_name = postData['last_name'], password = hashed_password)
            modelsResponse ['isRegistered']= True
            modelsResponse['user'] = user

        return modelsResponse

        def login_user(self, postData):
            user = self.filter(email = postData['email'])
            errors = []
            modelsResponse = {}
            if not user:
                #invalid email
                errors.append('Invalid email!')

            else:
                #found a user match, check the password to see if they match
                if bcrypt.checkpw(postData['password'].encode(), user[0].password.encode()):
                    #login the user
                    modelsResponse['isLoggedIn'] = True
                    modelsResponse['user'] = user[0]
                else:
                    # invalid email password combination
                    errors.append('Invalid email/password combination!')

            if errors:
                modelsResponse['isLoggedIn'] = False
                modelsResponse['errors'] = errors

        return modelsResponse

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    objects = UserManager()
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name= 'index'),
    url(r'^register$', views.register, name = 'register' ),
    url(r'^success$', views.success, name = 'success'),
    url(r'^login$', views.login, name = 'login' ),
    url(r'^logout$', views.logout, name = 'logout'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . models import User
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'logReg/index.html')

def register(request):
    viewsResponse = User.objects.add_user(request.POST)
    if viewsResponse['isRegistered']:
        request.session['user_id'] = viewsResponse['user'].id
        request.session['user_fname'] = viewsResponse['user'].first_name
        return redirect('users:success')
    else:
        for errors in viewsResponse['errors']:
            messages.error(request, errors)
        return redirect('users:index')


def success(request):
    if 'user_id' not in request.session:
        messages.error(request, 'Must be logged in!')
        return redirect('users.index')
    return render(request, 'logReg/success.html')

def login(request):
    viewsResponse = User.objects.login_user(request.POST)
    if viewsResponse['isLoggedIn']:
        request.session['user_id'] = viewsResponse['user'].id
        request.session['user_fname'] = viewsResponse['user'].first_name
        return redirect('users:success')
    else:
        for errors in viewsResponse['errors']:
            messages.error(request, errors)
        return redirect('users:index')

def logout(request):
    return redirect('users.index')
```

Comment: The indentation of `login_user` in `UserManager` is too much. Deindent it, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Well yes that fixed that one and gave me another lol  Think that one might be indent as well. post answer ill green check it

Comment: what is the other issue ? edit the question, and notify me

Comment: just put a print statement and see the contents of postdata. Does it have the `email` field in it ?

Comment: yea im going to work on it for a while i fix one error throws another lol I get it ty for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw a possible flaw in your code. You aren't creating the users with an email in your def add_user

```
user = self.create(first_name = postData['first_name'] , last_name = postData['last_name'], password = hashed_password
```

Try this code:

```
user = self.create(first_name = postData['first_name'] , last_name = postData['last_name'], email = postData['email'], password = hashed_password
```

Hope that at least gets you in the right direction.